# Query about piggybacked FIN & recieve

Tags: sockets, tcp

Will this code work in case piggybacked FIN is received ?

```
while(1) {

    rc = recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),MSG_WAITALL);

    if (rc > 0)
    {
        /* Code to process recv buf */
    }
    else if (rc == 0)
    {
        /* received FIN ?? */
        close(sock);
        break;
    }
    else /* rc < 0 */
    {
        /* Handle error */
        break;
    }
}
```

Would like to know if it would work or not and any alternate suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is data, `rc` will be positive, and your first `if` block will execute. If there is nothing left but a FIN next time, `rc` will be zero and your second block will execute.